# How to seperate class labels of hyperspectral images using R?

Tags: r, classification, data-mining, hyperspectral-sensor

[image: Aviris Indian pine site Ground truth]

The image has different classes and different band, where the 220 bands are separated by the following code

```
   library(RStoolbox)
   library(raster)
   library(rgdal) 
   library(caret)
   library(hyperSpec)


   img<-brick("19920612_AVIRIS_IndianPine_Site3.tif")

   names(img)
   names(img) <- c(paste0("B", 1:220, col = "")) 
   plot(img$B1) ## plotting Band 1 image
```

[image: Aviris Indian pine Site3-Band1]

How can we separate class labels such as alfalfa, corn-min etc from the above band?

Comment: What do you mean by "separate class labels"?

Comment: Hi Christopher, Class labels are mentioned in the first image (Ground truth) alfalfa, corn-
 mill etc

Comment: In in the second image - dont know to separate the class labels. Where I planned to train the each class labels to identify the pattern